# How can I save syntax in PgAdmin4 on my C: drive

Tags: postgresql, save, pgadmin-4

I'm brand new to postgreSQL, and I'm using Pgadmin4 as my GUI. I've been able to figure out how to save output tables to .csv files; however, I can't seem to figure out how to save the actual syntax from the query editor.

When I press the floppy disk, I'm taken to a directory and need to select where I want to put the file. The "Create" button stays muted and won't let me actually create a file.

I know that my query history is saved and I could always copy from there, but it would be nice to have a file that I could come back to.

[image: Picture for reference]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pgadmin user, but that looks similar to a GTK file chooser and I know how they work.

click in the top field of the file chooser (to the right of the last backslash of the path) and enter the rest of the filename you want to save as.